# Spice blend replacement?

Tags: spices

I have been using something called "Tandoori Blend" from spice hunter for years, but they don't seem to make it anymore. :(

I don't think it's a regular tandoori, since it's colored more like a [yellow] curry.
Was wondering if anyone else had used it and knows of a decent replacement, or a good recipe to recreate it from bulk spices.
[image: Ingredients]

Comment: A start would be the ingredients listed in the picture... Typically, they're listed in descending order of quantity.

Comment: “More like a yellow curry” - That would be the turmeric. It’s what makes curry powder yellow.

Comment: You could just order this: https://www.penzeys.com/online-catalog/tandoori-seasoning/c-24/p-114/pd-s

Comment: Guess I should've also asked if anyone know of another name for this particular blend of ingredients, as it doesn't seem to be too similar to other blends called tandoori.

Comment: You might want to start off with some garam masala, which is a very common Indian Spice blend. It contains most of what is listed there, minus the turmeric, cayenne/chilli powder, paprika, nutmeg, all of which you could add in small amounts.

Answer (score 1):

The colour from the spices can give us a hint as to the proportions.  With 12 ingredients, if they were in equal proportions you'd have 8% turmeric which is already going to do quite a bit to make it yellow.

But it won't have equal proportions: The cayenne and paprika would make it come out red or at least deep orange if so, and the nutmeg flavour would be too strong (possibly also the cardamom and black pepper.

You could get to about 16% turmeric if you had equal proportions of the top 6 ingredients, and tiny amounts of the remaining 6.  Reality will be somewhere in between.  I would suggest starting from 1 teaspoon of each ingredient (bought in ground form) down to the turmeric, and half a teaspoon of the ingredients after that, or maybe a little less.  If it looks too red, add more of all the top 6.

Then use it and taste the result.

You should choose whether to use hot or mild ("sweet") paprika based on whether you want much chilli heat; the cayenne will have some already.

Comment: This grew from a bunch of comments, especially under Max's answer, hence concentrating on the colour aspect, but we might as well use all the clues available

Answer (score -1):

You have the ingredients, just start mixing spices together and experiment.

That being said, there are tons of recipe for Tandoori spice blends out there; with similar ingredients list, they all have different ratios, again, pick one and experiment with it; they all taste different.

Color : They will also use Annatto seed top color the blend (and I'm sure some will also use red food coloring as a quick hack.)

Comment: Ummm, wouldn’t the manufacturer be required to list *all* ingredients, even if they are “just” colorants? We are talking about allergies and liabilities?

Comment: Not exactly in the US.  You can hide a lot by just listing ‘spices’ or ‘natural flavorings’.  But by not having some catch all terms, I don’t think they could do it legally, so I doubt there was annatto or other coloring in that particular blend.

Comment: I think he means that other people's blends use annatto.